# mediawiki-api - iterating through continue to get all results

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to create a list of all the subcategories in a category, and for all those subcategories, the basic categoryinfo for them.  (Number of files, subcategories, etc.)

I'm very close - just getting hung up on handling the continue process.

This gets me the first 100 results:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Google%20Art%20Project%20works%20by%20artist&gcmlimit=100&gcmprop=ids|title&prop=categoryinfo&continue=](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category%3aGoogle%20Art%20Project%20works%20by%20artist&gcmlimit=100&gcmprop=ids|title&prop=categoryinfo&continue=)

But, there are thousands of subcategories.

The result includes an xml node continue with gcmcontinue and continue attributes.

If I use that in my second request, this gives me the next 100 results:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Google%20Art%20Project%20works%20by%20artist&gcmlimit=100&gcmprop=ids|title&prop=categoryinfo&continue=gcmcontinue||&gcmcontinue=subcat|4c41555245c380204241525241550a474f4f474c45204152542050524f4a45435420574f524b53204259204c41555245c38020424152524155|38370707](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category%3aGoogle%20Art%20Project%20works%20by%20artist&gcmlimit=100&gcmprop=ids|title&prop=categoryinfo&continue=gcmcontinue||&gcmcontinue=subcat|4c41555245c380204241525241550a474f4f474c45204152542050524f4a45435420574f524b53204259204c41555245c38020424152524155|38370707)

BUT, that's where I'm having the problem.  These (second) set of results no longer have a continue xml node, so I'm not sure how to access the third page and so on.

(As a side note, I'm aware that if I wanted to - that I'd have to handle sub-sub-categories - but I don't need those, just the first level is fine.)

Comment: If I change gclimit to 50, I noticed I was able to keep iterating on subsequent pages with a chain of gcmcontinue's.  But, I maxed out at 200 still.  (4 pages of 50 total.)  I realized if you go to the live category at http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Google_Art_Project_works_by_artist it only shows 200 subcategories, then has a "next 200" link.  Perhaps that's why I'm only getting 200.  If so, how do I continue on?

Comment: /headslap

So, it helps to make sure you hit "commons.wikimedia.org" instead of "en.wikipedia.org" if you want the results from commons!

Sorry... I think that fixes the issue.  I'll say for sure soon.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  Able to get all the categories.  Can't answer my own question, too low reputation, so this sits open.

Comment: I think your solution won't be useful to anyone else, so you might considering deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

James' own answer: So, it helps to make sure you hit "commons.wikimedia.org" instead of "en.wikipedia.org" if you want the results from commons! That was the issue.